# Evaluating $\frac{100x^{100}+98x^{98}+96x^{96}+\cdots+6x^6+4x^4+2x^2}{99x^{99}+97x^{97}+95x^{95}+\cdots+5x^5+3x^3+x}$ for $x=99$ billion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics, computational-mathematics, math-software, big-numbers

> Approximately what is the value of $f$
> evaluated at $99$ billion, where
> \begin{equation*}
>         f(x) = \frac{100x^{100} + 98x^{98} + 96x^{96} + \dotsb + 6x^6+4x^4+2x^2}
>         {99x^{99}+97x^{97}+95x^{95}+\dotsb+5x^5+3x^3+x}\,?
>     \end{equation*}

This is an exam question. The purpose is to note for large $x$, $f(x) \approx \frac{100}{99}x$, but I'm curious how close this approximation is? Certainly the author is assuming here that the roots of the numerator and denominator are nowhere near $99$ billion. I want to know how close the approximation is to the true value. How can we actually compute $f(99\text{ billion})$?

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator by $x^{99}$ before evaluating.

Comment: To calculate $f99000000000)$ you could first simplify the expression for $f(x)$ by summing each series on the top and bottom of the fraction.

Comment: because all coefficients are positive, there are no positive real roots for both numerator and denominator according to the Descartes's rule of signs

Comment: " I'm curious how close this approximation is" not sure *I* care but if you divide num and denum by $x^{100}$ you get the $100+ \frac {98}{990000000000} < NUMERATOR < 100 + \frac {98.000000001}{99000000000}$ and $99 + \frac {97.000000001}{9801000000000000000000}> DENOMINATOR > 99+\frac{97}{9801000000000000000000}$ so our value is $\frac {100+ \frac {98}{990000000000} }{99 + \frac {97.000000001}{9801000000000000000000}} < VALUE < \frac {100 + \frac {98.000000001}{99000000000}}{ 99+\frac{97}{9801000000000000000000}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)$ can be explicitly computed as $$f(x) = \frac{100 x^{104}-102 x^{102}+2 x^2}{99 x^{103}-101 x^{101}+x^3+x}$$

Now just set $x$ to $99$ billions. Do you really want the exact value?

Here it is:

$$\frac{3697296376497267726572248748202039440378893622168736740033868932557908\
8556256235374714477514507679997593593949109344414606939296420208734101\
0676469462676931305920929634862131303428234710638975451616180501668137\
4288041210648062028509873153310821250394340865995372894273089905503376\
8877371486345647720439561322903521620203089198795236183472711910545136\
0485678762281740198667032548265228871457866150061692768582269235380656\
6512432305250121305580895021750348729056509720374375124519470574551353\
3493736050559453462153562276079705563853545473648174572669828131441147\
4126180048376162528066653906407647770923634051152194087662753429592288\
0098248439983536139909364655692178265236513144248146919690193447933318\
9868625573609810563825955675181203022354204099957893103593399511234818\
6772024340957132970493789310921637563413775084138110723387088254982549\
4728503220650500004033605770299423881130357516390331338732272198740764\
2154944818984755329149224842616398304491753416198555182993205626590511\
0459734131971351724748364089900007456522783255920000000570594029940000\
00000003881196000000000000000198000000000}{3697296376497267726572248671992615819468891105982828487383883413009855\
2181488381381098668226705780600581968853431174565978104075757257866607\
4364756069501495870305836791988097516926430080835310687276129629930444\
4219604449498554112850858976747756576236618537672853336397402664057666\
5160554173616690571170100361117856482955820430138206160215971840461540\
2056406217065610786471297627735380679938708139332086668426588322864776\
0032596202231320600218517379293406133529096413226541583445769643883641\
4423032276643275146844822980726612273151041276936346283704667478957023\
0000564015016144116466661236899949976550503780387362818666051158264148\
0697595393445815011603379511000069772132573908438150080613580011750972\
1242524254838703362313302708329046131950916016371590083156551311747070\
5253060951478228277223933812396382565790788973790653600703862530321466\
0655887841062605536700820157543876159661705744757781515226949069413567\
3589710758739665481224473234674619606515201833230968064856540782028250\
9684939011083047022498512809000006590361045807000000000480298005000000\
000000029403000000000000000001}$$

Since you are asking about how good is the approximation of $f(x)$ by $\frac{100}{99} x$ at $99$ billions we can calculate the difference:

$f(99\times 10^9) - \frac{100}{99}99\times10^9= 2.0612\ldots \times 10^{-15}$.

Pretty small.

Comment: Since this forum's language is english, I'm using the most common definition of "billion" in english, which is $10^9$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I intended for billion. How'd you compute that explicit formula? and how did you calculate that exact value? Your *exact* value must be off by some rounding errors looking at the right-most digits.

Comment: I get the same fraction with a raw calculation from the definition of $f(x)$ , eliminating the gcd of numerator and denominator

Comment: @MikePierce I derived the formulas using the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). I calculate the exact value using Mathematica, but many software packages and programming languages support arbitrary precision arithmetic. There is not rounding errors. What make you think there is something off?

Comment: @jjagmath Nah I was wrong. I wasn't considering the *whole* GCD of the numerator and denominator, just the factors of 10.

Comment: @jjagmath, Could we calculate the ratio instead? Is it just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 2):

If you are patient, make the long division and you will see that
$$f(x)=\frac{100 x}{99}\Bigg[1+\frac{1}{4950 x^2}+\frac{101}{490050
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right) \Bigg]$$ So, if $x=99\times 10^9$, the second term in brackets is
$$\frac 1{4851495\times 10^{19}}=2.06\cdots \times 10^{-26}$$ and the next one would be  $2.14\cdots \times 10^{-48}$

Answer (score 1):

Using Python big decimals, I get $$100\,000\,000\,000.0000000000000020612203042567...$$

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 1000000

x = Decimal (99000000000)
n= Decimal('0')
d=Decimal('0')

for i in range(100,0,-2):
  n += i*x**i

for i in range(99,0,-2):
  d += i*x**i

r= n/d

print("r = ", "{:.100f}".format(r) )
```